# Making Priority Search Tree with sorted y co-ordinates in O(n) time

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, computational-geometry

This is a exercise problem in the "computational geometry" book of "Mark de Berg, Otfried Cheong, Marc van Kreveld, Mark Overmars"

Chapter 10 Exercise 10.2:

> Let P be a set of n points in the plane, sorted on y-coordinate. Show
>   that, because P is sorted, a priority search tree of the points in P can be
>   constructed in O(n) time. Range queries are of the form (−∞ : q<sub>x</sub> ] × [q<sub>y</sub> : q`<sub>y</sub> ].

Here is what I have thought about this:

1. Create a Complete binary search tree (not a balanced binary search tree) from these point. This will be done in O(n) since point sorted based on y-values.
2. Build max heap from using bottom-up approach using the x-values. Again while doing that make the "y_mid" value of the node to the y-value of its left child.

This algorithm have some issue.
Consider this example:
after creating binary tree we have (ignore the y_mid value):

```
                             (50/8)
               (58/4)                      (33/12)
        (70/2)       (81/6)         (39/10)       (31/14)
    (28/1) (22/3) (71/5) (90/7) (57/9) (27/11) (48/13) (86/15)
```

This is the output after the build heap process:

```
                             (22/3)
               (28/1)                      (27/11)
        (50/8)       (71/5)         (33/12)       (31/14)
    (58/4) (70/2) (81/6) (90/7) (57/9) (39/10) (48/13) (86/15)
```

It can be observed that node (50/8) and (71/5) violate the priority of distribution of points. For whatever value at the median at parent, left y-value cannot be greater than the y-value at the right.
Similarly for (58/4) and (70/2) points.

My solution over this.
While building heap. I will make the swap of left and right child if they fail the property required. I am not sure whether this works or not.

The solution I need is pseudocode based.

If I want to implement so, heap with array based style exchanging this left and right pointer will be difficult.

Am I going in the right direction? If not what am I missing.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is to create a balanced binary search tree as follows.  The mid point is the root.  Recursively generate the tree on the left and the right.  Like this untested code.

```
def make_tree (elements, left=None, right=None):
    if left is None:
        left = 0
    if right is None:
        right = len(elements) - 1

    middle = (left + right) // 2
    answer = Node(middle)
    if left < middle:
        answer.left = make_tree(elements, left, middle - 1)
    if middle < right:
        answer.right = make_tree(elements, middle + 1, right)
    return answer
```

This function will be called once with each element as `middle`, and does `O(1)` work each time.  So it is `O(n)`.

Comment: This creates a BST. Why would it be `priority search tree`?